# Issues Testing Webservice Callouts

Tags: apex, webservices, webservicemock

I am trying to write a test class for a simple HTTP POST web service call. (I am just sending a three line json body to an endpoint).

Where I having trouble is trying to test my apex code. I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_static.htm). But I keep getting the following error: **"Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts"** . I tried a verbatim copy of what salesforce used and example and I get the same error. I am little lost as to how to proceed to test my code to get it deployed.

A big thank you in advance.

Here is a sample of my code I am trying to execute:

```
public class Play {

    @future (callout=true)
        public static void sendNotification(String name, String id) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        String Payload;

        req.setEndpoint('https://Endpoint');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic API KEY');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        payload = '{' + 
            '"companyName":"' + name + '",' +
            '"salesforceId":"'+ id + '",' +
            '"salesforceAccountType": "Company",' +
            '"salesforceSynchStatus": "Enabled" }';

        req.setBody( payload );
        req.setCompressed(true); 

        try {
            res = http.send(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my test I am trying to tinker with

```
@isTest
private class PlayTest {
    @isTest static void testCalloutWithStaticResources() {

        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
        mock.setStaticResource('mockResponse');
        mock.setStatusCode(200);
        mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        HTTPResponse res = Play.sendNotification('My Test Customer','0011a00000LWmil');

        System.assertEquals('{"hah":"fooled you"}', res.getBody());
        System.assertEquals(200,res.getStatusCode());
        System.assertEquals('application/json', res.getHeader('Content-Type'));   
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure you called Test.setMock *before* attempting to make any callouts?

Comment: Thank you for writing back! I did get a message saying Illegal assignment from void to System.HttpResponse

Comment: I think you'd be better off posting your unit test code so we can see exactly what's going on. It sounds like you've got a couple of things going on. You can [edit] your question to provide the code.

Comment: I have added the code!

Answer (score 8):

You have two problems here:

(a) Your future method isn't being called.

You have to call Test.stopTest in order to call asynchronous code.

(b) Your future method can't return data.

If you want to store the results somewhere, you have to set a variable somehow and refer to the data later.

Here's an updated version of your class `Play`:

```
public class Play {
    @TestVisible static HttpResponse res;

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void sendNotification(String name, String id) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        Http http = new Http();
        String payload = JSON.serialize(
            new Map<String, String> {
                'companyName' => name,
                'salesforceId' => id,
                'salesforceAccountType' => 'Company',
                'salesforceSynchStatus' => 'Enabled'
            }
        );

        req.setEndpoint('https://Endpoint');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic API KEY');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(payload.length());

        req.setBody( payload );
        req.setCompressed(true); 

        try {
            res = http.send(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And, here's the related updates to your test class:

```
@isTest private class PlayTest { 
    @isTest static void testCalloutWithStaticResources() {
        StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
        mock.setStaticResource('mockResponse');
        mock.setStatusCode(200);
        mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);

        Test.startTest();
        Play.sendNotification('My Test Customer','0011a00000LWmil');
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals('{"hah":"fooled you"}', Play.res.getBody());
        System.assertEquals(200,Play.res.getStatusCode());
        System.assertEquals('application/json', Play.res.getHeader('Content-Type'));   
    }
}
```

---

As a side note, I generally frown on generating JSON by hand. In this case, you have a bug: if your account name has a `"` in it, it'll break your JSON. Instead, you should always use a JSON method to generate your payload:

```
String payload = JSON.serialize(
    new Map<String, String> {
        'companyName' => name,
        'salesforceId' => id,
        'salesforceAccountType' => 'Company',
        'salesforceSynchStatus' => 'Enabled'
    }
);
```

---

Also, most services require a Content-Length for POST actions, so you might need to explicitly set that value:

```
req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(payload.length());
```

Comment: A genuine thank you! I have definitely learned a bunch.